# Exists an explicit formula to calculate the minimum $n$ for some $x$ such that $\frac{x}{2^n}\in[0,0.5)+\Bbb Z$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For any $x \in \Bbb R$ I want to know if exist an explicit formula that evade recursion to calculate the **minimum *n*** such that

$$\frac{x}{2^n}\in[0,0.5)+\Bbb Z$$

where $[0,0.5)+\Bbb Z$ is an uncountable union of equivalent classes that belong to the quotient group $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$. We can try to symbolize the same, with some abuse of notation, as

$$0\le\frac{x}{2^n}<0.5\pmod 1$$

for $n\in \Bbb N_{\ge 0}$. What I want is the minimum $n$ where the fractional part of $x$ is less than $0.5$. Notice that if $x$ is an integer then $n=0$.

Comment: The notation doesn't quite make mathematical sense: equivalence mod 10 is a relation between integers, but $x/2^n$ is definitely not an integer.  My guess is that you want the minimum positive integer $n$ such that $x/2^n + 10 y \in [0,5)$ for some integer $y$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael maybe Im very wrong here, you can take congruence for rational or irrational numbers? What I was searching is the minimum _n_ where a number had a rest less than .5

Answer (score 2):

(I'm also assuming $n$ should be a positive integer.) To solve this problem, simply write the integer $\lfloor x/10\rfloor$ in binary. Then $n$ is given by the position of the rightmost $0$ in that binary expansion. For example, if $\lfloor x/10\rfloor = 101100111$ in binary, then $n=4$, since the number ends in $0111$.

Comment: Maybe is the same, I edited the question to clarify, sry for the inconvenience but something in this line. Yes, changing the numeric base seems the answer that I was searching for.

Comment: I edited the state of "answer" to this, sry, because I realized that changing the base of a number is a recursive operation what explicitly is something that I want evade. Sry for the inconvenience, anyway the contribution is really appreciated and lightener.